# How to manage URLs of a website with different articles?

Tags: php, database, match, blogs

I have made a sample website with some articles. The way I want the URLs to be is like:

> www.example.com/news/first-article

however, for now, I have just placed the required **first-article.html** file in the directory by first creating the directory: `home/news/`.

Thing to be noted is that I do have all the contents of the article (such as heading, body, date, etc.) saved in a Database, so I feel like there might be a better way such as **URI matcher** present in Android, instead of just creating file in each directory.

The motive here is to identify the category of the article (here '**news**') and the name of the article (here '**first-article**') and then to retrieve details from DB and generate the required page dynamically. Is this possible in PHP?

[A sample code snippet could would help]

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a single PHP page to read from the database, and display the content based on a `$_GET` parameter:

```
include('database_connection.php'); // Saved as $mysqli

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $news_id = $_GET['id'];

    // Grab the news information given the ID (in MySQLi)
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, news, date FROM news WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $news_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $news, $date);
    $stmt->fetch();

    // Output results
    echo "<h1>" . $date . "</h1>";
    echo "<p"> . $news . "</p>";

    $stmt->close();
}
```

This will only require one PHP page (`news.php`), which loads various articles with `news.php?id=1`, `news.php?id=2`, etc.

Then you could use `.htaccess` to 'morph' the news pages into 'pretty' pages with something like this following:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) news.php?id=$1&$2
```

When you link using something like:

```
$article_title = 'First Article';
echo '<a href="' . str_replace(" ", "-", $article_title).'">Read More</a>';
```

Which will 'prettify' your page URLs, based on the script filenames.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: with this method, will I have to share the final link as `example.com/news/first` or `example.com?id=2`  ?